# Are there any increasing or decreasing intervals of a quadratic equation with no real values of $x$?

Tags: quadratics, maxima-minima

> Using first derivative test, find the increasing/decreasing intervals and local maximum and local minimum values of the function $f(x) = x^3 -3x^2 - 6x$

$$f'(x)= 3x^2 -6x -6=0 $$
what do I write for this type of question ?

Comment: $f(x)$ is cubic, not quadratic

Comment: $$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$

Comment: yes but then i have to take the derivative of f(x)

Comment: and i did find the discriminant its a negative value which means there are no value of x so then what does that mean for the intervals ?

Comment: What do you mean by "intervals (...) with no real values of $x$ "?

Comment: there are no crtical points for the function so there will be no minima and maxima for it but what about the increasing and decreasing intervals what do i write for them ?

Comment: in the question they are asking for the intervals

Comment: What did you get for the discriminant?  It's positive

Comment: You can solve $f'(x)=0$ to give two real solutions

Comment: ohh its actually positive thanks but now how do i find the roots for this function ? can i use middle term split method

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?  You’ll get expressions involving square roots

Comment: yes but i will get a decimal value for that so should i use that in this question

Comment: thank you for your help i actually calculated the wrong discriminant so i thought there are no values but there are so thanks i will do it from here then

Comment: Note:  $6x^2+6x+6$ has negative discriminant, so $2x^3+3x^2+6x$ is monotonic. 
 (Your example is not like that.)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^3-3x^2-6x$$

$$f'(x)=3x^2-6x-6=0$$

$$f'(x)=x^2-2x-2=0$$

$$D=(-2)^2-4\times 1\times (-2)=12$$

$x_1=1-\sqrt{3}$, $x_2=1+\sqrt{3}$

The function is increasing (because $f'(x)>0$) in $(-\infty,1-\sqrt{3})$ and increasing (because $f'(x)>0$) in $(1+\sqrt{3},\infty)$ , decreasing (because $f'(x)<0$) in $(1-\sqrt{3},1+\sqrt{3})$

And there is a local minimum for $x=1+\sqrt{3}$, a local maximum for $x=1-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: What about $(1+\sqrt3,\infty)$?

Comment: i got maxima =2.4 and minima= - 18.4

Comment: $f(1-\sqrt{3})=2.4$ is the maximum value and $f(1+\sqrt{3})=-18.4$ is the minimum value

Comment: yes i got exactly that thank you for your help sir

Comment: You are welcome